# Maven latest version update failed with mvn install command

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have using latest version of MAVEN. I have to projects which I want to build using MAVEN. 
My first project is a module based project which has two modules. Parent POM for this project consists 2 child POMS. I am going to Pass version as variable through command prompt to make this build independent of static version.

My **parent POM** looks like :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>A.B.C</groupId>
<artifactId>D</artifactId>
<version>${major.version}.${build.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- Some further code-->
```

**One Module** have POM like :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>A.B.C</groupId>
    <artifactId>D</artifactId>
    <version>${major.version}.${build.version}</version>
</parent>

**<groupId>A.B.C</groupId> 
<artifactId>E</artifactId>**
<version>${major.version}.${build.version}</version>

<!-- Some further code-->
```

**Second Module** have POM like :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>A.B.C</groupId>
    <artifactId>F</artifactId>
    <version>${major.version}.${build.version}</version>
</parent>

**<groupId>A.B.C</groupId> 
<artifactId>G</artifactId>**
<version>${major.version}.${build.version}</version>

<!-- Some further code-->
```

**My Second project uses above dependency in its POM like :**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>A.B.C</groupId>
<artifactId>T</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        **<groupId>A.B.C</groupId> 
        <artifactId>E</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>**
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        **<groupId>A.B.C</groupId> 
        <artifactId>G</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>**
    </dependency>
```

But while using **mvn clean install**, it gives error for

*[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project T: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact A.B.C:D:pom:${major.version}.${build.version} from/to nexus-all-repos : IllegalArgumentException*

But if I use command **mvn versions:use-latest-versions**, it works fine. I want to use **mvn install** as I want to use latest version for some dependencies only.

**What might be the issue?**

Adding complete error stack

```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project T: Could not resolve dependencies for project A.B.C:T:jar:5.6.0.15: Failed to collect dependencies at A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST: Failed to read artifact descriptor for A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST: Could not tran
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project T: Could not resolve dependencies for project A.B.C:T:jar:5.6.0.15: Failed to collect dependencies at A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project A.B.C:T:jar:5.6.0.15: Failed to collect dependencies at A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:159)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for A.B.C:E:jar:LATEST
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:261)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact A.B.C:D:pom:${major.version}.${build.version} from/to nexus-all-repos (http://eqmavenrepo.technologic.com/nexus/content/groups/allrepo/): IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:170)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:898)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:750)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:375)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact A.B.C:D:pom:${major.version}.${build.version} from/to nexus-all-repos (http://eqmavenrepo.technologic.com/nexus/content/groups/allrepo/): IllegalArgumentException
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:166)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact A.B.C:D:pom:${major.version}.${build.version} from/to nexus-all-repos (http://eqmavenrepo.technologic.com/nexus/content/groups/allrepo/): IllegalArgumentException
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1016)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$6.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:1004)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:725)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:841)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:660)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 119: http://eqmavenrepo.technologic.com/nexus/content/groups/allrepo/A/B/C/D/${major.version}.${build.version}/D-${major.version}.${build.version}.pom
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)
        ... 10 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

**Still getting error after removing illegal characters**

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way Maven works. Don't look at the POM as a mere build script, but more as a delivery slip shipped together with your artifact that explains how it is connected to the rest of the world, e.g. in terms of dependencies and *how* it was **built** (note the past tense), not how to build it, like Ant.

The problem is that *if* Maven would allow you to parameterize `${major.version}.${build.version}` and use them as coordinates, when it installs/deploys it *might* be able to do right thing and deploy your artifact to `http://.../E/X.Y/E-X.Y.pom` (if you used `mvn -Dmajor.version=X -Dbuild.version=Y ...`).

But then the problem comes later. Another user *might* download your artifact correctly, but when Maven tries to parse the POM, it will encounter `${major.version}.${build.version}` and wouldn't know what to do because the actual values were provided by you when you deployed and are lost in the process.

This is the reason why Maven coordinates need to be fixed and are not extrapolated with properties; it gives you (and perhaps more importantly, any other dependant) control and traceability. Of course, other non-coordinate properties may be parameterized to your heart's content, it's just coordinates that are more sensitive to this.

> Maven coordinates uses five values, three of them more common than the other: `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`. The other two are `packaging` and `classifier`, but are used for more exotic use-cases.

I would advise you to rethink your building approach if you are going to use Maven. It has a steep learning curve, but the view is magnificent from the top. Releasing artifacts using Maven is better done through, for instance, the [Maven Release plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

i think problem related to wrong symbols in path to repo cuz this is in stacktrace. try check all paths related to nexus repo.

```
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 119: ~^~content/groups/allrepo/~^~/E/${major.version}.${build.version}/E-${major.version}.${build.version}.pom
```